# Setting options to images in Magick .NET collection

Tags: c#, magick.net

I'm trying to reduce the file sizes of the GIF animations I'm exporting, I've read up on how to do it. Another thread suggested to reduce the quality, add compression and slightly blur the picture which is what I'm trying to do like so:

```
using (MagickImageCollection col = new MagickImageCollection(@"C:/PathToGif"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
            {
                col[i].Quality = 85;
                col[i].CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.LZW;
                col[i].Strip();
            }

            col.Write(@"C:/Path/To/Outputh");
        }
```

The code runs however the settings seem to be ignored, while setting `AnimationDelay` the same way does work. I verify it by checking the quality and file size of the output, which seem to be the same as when I don't use any of the settings. Even setting `quality` to 20, gives the same results.

I've also attempted to use `QuantizeSettings` where I passed a value of `255` to the `colors` property. Which just seemed to lock my application up, while using 50% CPU. (I gave it about 5 minutes before forcefully closing the application)

My application processes a .GIF of about 950 kB and turns it into 5.3 mB which is unacceptable. (Disclaimer: I add about 20+- frames to the .GIF and draw an overlay on it.)

Could someone who has experience with the Magick .NET library tell me if I'm doing something wrong and point me into the right direction of doing this? I was unable to find a different way of applying these settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GIF coder does not use the Quality setting and the CompressionMethod will always be CompressionMethod.LZW. You should do the following if you want to optimize the output file:

```
using (MagickImageCollection col = new MagickImageCollection(@"C:/PathToGif"))
{
  col.Coalesce();

  AddOtherImages(col);

  col.Optimize();
  col.OptimizeTransparency();

  col.Write(@"C:/Path/To/Output");
}
```

Make sure you upgrade to the latest version, the Optimize/OptimizeTransparency methods were bugged in previous versions.